# Mouse Pointer inside the Textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a textbox(asp.net) with the mouse pointer as hand symbol.On making the `textbox` property `Disabled` for the textbox , the **hand symbol is not shown**.(below code -style is not working).

On making text box to read only the hand symbol is showing. But on click of the textbox the mouse pointer is showing inside the textbox.I don't want to see the mouse pointer inside the textbox.

So how can i make either one of this possible :

- How can i **avoid the mouse pointer inside the textbox** on click of the textbox **but must show the hand symbol** on mouse over of the textbox(when the textbox is Read only)
  **or**
- How can i make the `textbox.enabled=false` with the hand symbol.

Thanks in advance

```
<style>
.txtclass{cursor:pointer;}
 </style
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Try this out:-

```
<style type="text/css">
    .myTextBox{cursor:pointer;}
</style>
<asp:TextBox ID="myTextBox" runat="server" disabled="disabled" CssClass="myTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
```

**EDIT**

Working fine at my end.

[image]

**Edit 2**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .myTextBox
    {
        width: 200px;
        margin: 1em auto;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        height: 20px;
        background: #ededed;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
<div id="myTextBox" class="myTextBox" runat="server">
    abs
</div>
```

Comment: <style type="text/css">
    .myTextBox{cursor:pointer;}
</style>
<asp:TextBox ID="myTextBox" runat="server" disabled="disabled" CssClass="myTextBox"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: Iam musing visual web developer 2010 express

Comment: Are there any other CSS classes which getting applied to this textbox?

Comment: No .For trying i pasted in a new form

Comment: on which browser you are testing?

Comment: IE 7/8/9 which version?

Comment: You can add `onfocus="this.blur()"` with `Readonly="true"`

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="myTextBox" runat="server" onfocus="this.blur()" CssClass="myTextBox" 
             ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>      Now hand symbol is showing but on click mouse pointer is showing inside the textbox

Comment: sorry didn't worked.On using this.blur -> the hand symbol is showing but on click mouse pointer is also showing.Thanks

Comment: If there is text inside it is working (Disabled=disabled) code is working)

Comment: so use disabled with empty spaces as values.

Comment: But only until the text last.ie if the textbox is big and the text is abs then the hand symbol is showing until abs after that for empty portion it is just showing arrow symbol

Comment: values are retrieving from the database.

Comment: @abcdshsu - Please see Edit 2, and let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css

```
input[disabled], select[disabled], textarea[disabled], input[readonly], select[readonly], textarea[readonly] {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use two classes

```
.txtclass1{cursor:default;}
```

and

```
.txtclass2{cursor:pointer;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wiz kid, thanks

By making both Read only -true and Enabled-false made the text box visible with hand symbol and with out cursor( on click of the textbox)

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txt" CssClass="txtclass" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval   (Container.DataItem, "License") %>' Enabled="False" Width="50px" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
```